# NFS persistent volume is not deleted even with "Delete" persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, containers, nfs, persistent-volumes

I am using `NFS` `Persistent Volume` to create PV.

The reclaim policy being used in `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete.`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /
    server: fs-0bb.efs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I delete my `deployment-controller` and also delete `PersistentVolumeClaim`, the NFS volume is not getting deleted.

**Expected Behaviour:** `The NFS PV volume should be deleted after PVC is deleted.`

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of PV configurations one is Static PV and the other is dynamic PV, if you have configured Static PV you need to delete both PVC and PV. For dynamic PV you just need to delete the PVC and then the PV will be released. From the manifest file you have provided it seems that you are using static PV, so you need to delete both PVC and PV.